# contains() always returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically created table and when I add new row I need to check if a book already exists in the table or not.

```
function drawRow(obj) {
    var row = $("<tr>")
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.Id + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.bookno+ "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.isbn + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));

    if ($(".bktbl tr").contains == obj.isbn) { // It shows me always false. I think this is not working properly
        alert("Already there!");
    } else {
        $(".bktbl table").append(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: [contains()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) is a function, not a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) along with length property

> Select all elements that contain the specified text.

```
 if($(".bktbl tr:contains('"+obj.isbn+"')").length)
```

instead of

```
 if ($(".bktbl tr").contains == obj.isbn) {
```